# The importance of estimates of frame bounds.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, applications

A theorem contained in

> Christensen, Ole (1995), "A Paley-Wiener theorem for frames."
>   Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 123, 2199-2201.

states that

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ be a frame for a Hilbert space $H$ with
>   bounds $A$ and $B$. Let $\{y_n\}_{n \in\mathbb Z}\subset H$ be such
>   that the inequality $\left\|\sum_ n a_n (x_n-y_n)\right\|^2\leq C 
>  \sum_n |a_n|^2 $ is valid  with a constant $0< C<A$.  Then,
>   $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is a frame with bounds $A'\ge
>  (1-(\mbox{$\frac C A$})^{\frac 12})^2 $ and $B'\leq (1+(\mbox{$\frac C
>  A$})^{\frac 12})^2 $. If $\{x_n\}_{n \in\mathbb Z}$ is a Riesz basis,
>   then $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is also a Riesz basis.

This theorem allows to estimate the frames bounds of a frame by knowing the frame bounds of another frame. My question is maybe too naive, but why should we determine the estimates of frames bounds? Does someone know an application where these estimates are important? Thanks!

Comment: May it be that the frame bound estimates for $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ should read
$A'\le A\left(1-\sqrt{C\,/ A}\,\right)^2$ and $B\big(1+\sqrt{C\,/B}\,\big)^2\le B'\,?$